# Why seaborn with displot irregular

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, seaborn

I used the script:

```
sns.displot(data=df, x='New Category', height=5, aspect=3, kde=True)
```

but the data not irregular like this pict
I want the order to be like this::

- Less than 2 hours
- Between 1 to 2 hours
- Between 2 to 4 hours
- Between 4 to 6 hours
- Between 6 to 12 hours
- More than 12 hours

The Result of Script:

[image: The Result of Script]

Comment: Side note, the KDE curve is not showing anything meaningful here.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to fix an order, is via `pd.Categorical`:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# first, create some test data
categories = ['Less than 2 hours', 'Between 1 to 2 hours', 'Between 2 to 4 hours',
              'Between 4 to 6 hours', 'Between 6 to 12 hours', 'More than 12 hours']
weights = np.random.rand(len(categories)) + 0.1
weights /= weights.sum()
df = pd.DataFrame({'New Category': np.random.choice(categories, 1000, p=weights)})

# fix an order on the column via pd.Categorical
df['New Category'] = pd.Categorical(df['New Category'], categories=categories, ordered=True)

# displot now uses the fixed order 
sns.displot(data=df, x='New Category', height=5, aspect=3, kde=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: fix an order for sns.displot]

Comment: can the result of Count must be same like the first?, the more than 12 hours the last position

Comment: Can you elaborate your question a bit?  Also note that your post is missing test data.

Comment: My example uses the order as described in the question, with "more than 12" at the end.  It is just an example, you can set any order you want.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is the order in the original df:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'test': ['Less than 2 hours', 'Less than 2 hours', 'Less than 2 hours', 'Less than 2 hours', 'Between 1 to 2 hours', 'Between 2 to 4 hours', 'Between 4 to 6 hours', 'Between 6 to 12 hours', 'More than 12 hours', 'More than 12 hours']})
sns.displot(data=df, x='test', height=5, aspect=3, kde=True)
```

result:

[image]

While:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'test': ['Less than 2 hours', 'Less than 2 hours', 'Less than 2 hours', 'Less than 2 hours', 'Between 1 to 2 hours', 'Between 2 to 4 hours', 'Between 4 to 6 hours','More than 12 hours', 'More than 12 hours', 'Between 6 to 12 hours']})
sns.displot(data=df, x='test', height=5, aspect=3, kde=True)
```

result:

[image]

so, use:

```
mapping = {'Less than 2 hours': 0, 'Between 1 to 2 hours':1, 'Between 2 to 4 hours': 2, 'Between 4 to 6 hours': 3, 'Between 6 to 12 hours': 4, 'More than 12 hours': 5}
out = []
for val in df['test']:
    out.append(mapping[val])
df['ord'] = out
df = df.sort_values('ord')
sns.displot(data=df, x='test', height=5, aspect=3, kde=True)
```

Comment: can the result of Count must be same like the first?, the more than 12 hours the last position

Comment: I am not confident that understand you well, but my solution just need you set the position as you desired. The last one with the grater number in mapping dic.